# CsvBulkLoader import/update only existing objects

Tags: csv, import, silverstripe

I'm using a simple CsvBulkLoader to bulk update dataobjects.

```
class OrderImporter extends CsvBulkLoader {
    public $delimiter = ';';
    public $enclosure = '"';
    public $hasHeaderRow = true;

    public $columnMap = array(
      'ID' => 'ID',
      'Bezahlt' => 'Payed',
            'Geandert' => 'NeedReview'
    );
}
```

My problem is, that I don't want to create new objects, If they are in the import file. I only want to update the existing ones.

Is there a way to achieve this? Sadly I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have a look at `CsvBulkLoader::processRecord()`. This is where each line is processed. You could try in your OrderImporter class (untested):

```
protected function processRecord($record, $columnMap, &$results, $preview = false) {
        // find existing object
        $existingObj = $this->findExistingObject($record, $columnMap);
        return ($existingObject) 
            ? parent::processRecord($record, $columnMap, $results, $preview)
            : false;
    }
```

HTH, wmk

Comment: good idea but I receive a `Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed` error for **parent::processRecord** right after entering the backend.

Comment: Even after solving this error, it seams that now nothing gets imported. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set $duplicateChecks based on what fields already existing in your DB can be checked against the import file. If the IDs match you can use:

```
public $duplicateChecks = array(
        'ID' => 'ID',
);
```

You should test the import on a dev server first, especially if you use a combination of fields, as the results can be different from what you're expecting.

See $duplicateChecks in the BulkLoader api http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-BulkLoader.html

Comment: Sry it's been a while. Perhapse you could help me, I've got the duplicate check with a Callback on ID. But I can't figure out how to go on.